# How do you get a label to pull in text from another label in Swift?

Tags: swift

I wish to pull text from one label and embed it in a string in another label.

For example.

```
label1.text = "Stack"

button1.setTitle("label1.text" "Overflow", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [String Interpolation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/swift/conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/StringsAndCharacters.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH7-XID_443)

```
button1.setTitle( "\(label1.text) Overflow", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
```

Comment: This now displays the word optional("3")Overflow for the following code:  button1.setTitle( "\(label4.text) Overflow", forState: UIControlState.Normal)  Any ideas?

Comment: Try adding an ! after .text to unwrap the Optional. Actually this should work just so according to the Internets but you never know

Answer (score 0):

If:

```
label1.text = "Stack"
```

and you want to append `"Overflow"`, you can do:

```
let label = label1.text + " Overflow"
button1.setTitle(label, forState: UIControlState.Normal)
```

or more succintly:

```
button1.setTitle(label1.text + " Overflow", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
```

You may deduct that to concatenate 2 strings you can use the `+` operator.
Alternatively you can use string interpolation as suggested by @SebastianWramba in his answer